# Loop Combobox and variable inside

Tags: vb.net, loops, variables, combobox

I have this code:

```
Dim val1,val2,val3,val4,val5, ... ,val20 As String

If Combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
   val1=">"
else
   val1="<"
end if

If Combobox2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
   val2=">"
else
  val2="<"
end if
```

How can I loop this? There are 20 Combo boxes. Please help! Thanks

Comment: You can shorten your code `val1 = If(Combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0, ">", "<")`

Comment: Are val1, val2, val3, etc. declared as **locals** in a method?...or are they class level variables?  It'd probably be easier just to implement this using a Dictionary with the ComboBox **name** as the Key.

Comment: @Idle_Mind That's what I just said (below)

Comment: @T.S. thanks, i will use it. but is it possible to loop it? Cause I really want to loop it so bad. Well, I'm a girl, a student fyi ^_^

Comment: @Idle_Mind this is what I actually want to do https://www.daniweb.com/articles/view/499132 . I'm new so I don't know how design a good program.

Comment: If you connect control name to a property or a key - you can loop both ways. For example, if you create `Dictionary(of string, string)`, you can do then, on `cbo_SelectedIndexChanged` -> `cbo = ctype(sender, combobox) myDict(cbo.Name) = If(cbo.SelectedIndex = 0, ">", "<")`.

Comment: @T.S. I'm sorry but I don't understand. Where should I do the looping? Can you explain more as a answer? I'm sorry

Comment: @m.kr_newbie Ok, check my answer than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through the controls on the form, use `Me.Controls`. And to check the type of the control, use `Control.GetType.Name`.

The problem is that separate variables like `val1,val2,val3...etc` cannot be easily used in a loop, so I recommend changing them to a list.

```
Dim val As New List(Of String)

For Each MyControl In Me.Controls
    If MyControl.GetType.Name = "ComboBox" Then
        Dim MyComboBox As ComboBox = CType(MyControl, ComboBox)
        If MyComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            val.Add(">")
        Else
            val.Add("<")
        end if
    End If
Next
```

Comment: How is he going to match value to a combo-box? Gotta use either dictionary or list of mapping object

Comment: Not necessarily. It all depends on his design which we don't know. He originally had `val1,val2...etc`, which mapped to `ComboBox1,ComboBox2...etc`, so I assumed that index mapping was enough. If his form has the combo-boxes on it in that order, then the index of the list is enough for mapping and there is no need for a dictionary. This way `val(0)` will be mapped to `ComboBox1` and `val(1)` will be mapped to `ComboBox2`....etc.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thank you, but if I use it that way I have to declare the value of each "val" can not declare it as a group.
my goal is to make the code as little as possible with many loop. or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. This is about the shortest code possible. `val` is a list that has one value for each `ComboBox`.

Comment: @RacilHilan Sorry for the late respond, Yes it is, the code is cool. But I have to type Dim val1 as string = "" to set the value. I have to type it one by one. I can't type Dim val1, val2, val3 as string = "". There is warning 'Variable is used before it has been assigned a value'. If I can type only one line, that will be great. Cause I have to print the code out, I wish my code could look short and difficult..:)

Comment: But using my code you don't need to type `Dim val1, val2, val3` anymore. You only need `Dim val As New List(Of String)` like I mentioned in my code. `val` is a list of string values (like an array) and it holds one string value for each `ComboBox`. When you want to retrieve those values somewhere else in your code, you use `val(0)` to retrieve the value for `ComboBox1`, and `val(1)` to retrieve the value for `ComboBox2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, here are some looping sequences for you. disclaimer - code is not tested, could be bugs but logical layout should be correct

```
Private _numOfControls As Integer = 20
Private _variables As New Dictionary(Of String, String)(_numOfControls)

Private Sub Setup()

    For i as integer = 1 To _numOfControls 

        Dim cboName As String = "cbo" & i
        Dim cbo As New ComboBox()
        cbo.Name = cboName 
        cbo.SelectedIndex = 0
        ' Add cbo location according to your logic here
        container.Controls.Add(cbo) ' container - any control or form that hosts cbo

        _variables.Add(cboName, ">")
        AddHandler cbo.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf OnCboSelectedIndexChanged
    Next
End Sub

' If you do this way, your control-related variable will have appropriate equality sign without need for iteration
Private Sub OnCboSelectedIndexChanged (sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim cbo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    myDict(cbo.Name) = If(cbo.SelectedIndex = 0, ">", "<")

End Sub

' But if you do not want to do in the above^^ way, you can iterate dictionary
Private Sub FromDictionaryToCbo()
    ' Here you can't use for-loop on dictionary because your dictionary will be mutating. So lets iterate keys
    For Each k As String In _variables.Keys.ToArray())

        _variables(k) = If(CType(container.Find(k, True), ComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0, ">", "<")

    Next
End Sub

' And iterating combo boxes would be something similar as another answer here
' But we use our naming convention to bypass other controls
Private Sub FromCboToDictionary()

    Dim c As Control
    For i As Integer = 1 To < _numOfControls
        Dim key As String = "cbo" & i.ToString()

        'We don't know, may be there some other combo boxes are there, so we use our naming convention instead of control type 
        c = container.Find(key, True)

        If c IsNot Nothing Then

            _variables(key) = If(CType(c, ComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0, ">", "<")    
        end If       
    Next

End Sub
```